# Extending Independence of Random Variables to Sigma Algebra of Preimages

Tags: probability, measure-theory, random-variables

Given independent random variables $X,Y :\Omega \to \mathbb R$ is it possible to extend their independence to the sigma algebra generated by their preimages?

Comment: Isn't this the definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated by @kimchi lover you cannot speak of a proper extension here. To make things more clear:

It can be shown that:
$$\sigma(X)=\{X^{-1}(A')\mid A'\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R)\}$$

So if $A\in\sigma(X)$ then a Borel measurable set $A'\subseteq\mathbb R$ will exist with $A=\{X\in A'\}$, and likewise if $B\in\sigma(Y)$ then a Borel measurable set $B'\subseteq\mathbb R$ will exist with $B=\{Y\in B'\}$.

Then by independence of $X,Y$: $$P(A\cap B)=P(\{X\in A'\wedge Y\in B'\})=P(\{X\in A'\})P(\{Y\in B'\})=P(A)P(B)$$

Comment: Sorry, there was a misunderstanding on my part, its resolved and thanks for the answer.